# Which options (emit or scope-slot) should be used in this situation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[image: Click To Show Image]

Above screenshot is a main body which contains a search and a sidebar component.

When I click on search drop down component, items appear and then when I click on an item, the sidebar will be updated. When the user clicks on a sidebar item (e.g. the close button) or unselects the item from the dropdown, it should disappear from the sidebar.

So now is it good to use `$emit` or scope-slot?

Comment: Best answer to have two components talk to each other is to use vuex. When you click on an item in the search component, it gets added to an item in the store through mutations. Meanwhile in the side component, you simply import the store and let the reactivity handle it.

Comment: Most probably it is the best way(better than the two ways mentioned which are not properly). but I don't know vuex . so I prefer to understand this concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use vuex if you are going to do more complex things in future but if you are planning to do the above implementation only then I think `$emit` is better since it is more simple than scope-slot (According to my knowledge).